# Visualizing the Partition numbers (suggestions for visualization techniques)

Tags: fractals, integer-partitions, visualization

So [Ken Ono says](http://blogs.plos.org/badphysics/2011/01/20/ono/) that the partition numbers behave like fractals, in which case I'd like to try to find an appropriately illuminating way of visualizing them. But I'm sort of stuck at the moment, so here I'm asking for suggestions for visualization methods.

Comment: I'd love to see this as well.

Comment: Related discussion on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106135/visualizing-the-l-adic-fractal-in-the-partition-function-pn

Comment: @deoxygerbe: +1 for this nice reference!